# Как задать внешние стили компоненту React?

Tags: reactjs

Есть компонент `Button`, у него есть свои стили. Но в зависимости от того, где находится сам `Button`, у него могут быть внешние отступы или другие свойства для размещения внутри родительского блока.

Код для `Button`

```
export default class Button extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return <button className="button">
      <span className="button_text">
        {this.props.children}
      </span>
     </button>
  }
}
```

Добавить стили таким образом не получается

```
<Button className="popup_button">Отправить</Button>
```

Если делаю так, работает, но дополнительная обертка не выглядит, как хорошее решение

```
<div className="popup_button">
  <Button>Узнать больше</Button>
</div>
```

Как же тогда задавать эти стили для отступов и размеров?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хех. Не зря я целый месяц учил React... Вот так парень:

```
export default class Button extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return <button className={this.props.className}>
      <span className="button_text">
        {this.props.children}
      </span>
     </button>
  }
}
```

Можно даже захардкодить вот так:

```
export default class Button extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return <button {...this.props}>
      <span className="button_text">
        {this.props.children}
      </span>
     </button>
  }
}
```